# How do I play multiplayer?

Tags: doom, doom-3-bfg-edition

I have bought DOOM 3 BFG edition, which includes The Ultimate DOOM and DOOM 2, in addition to the expansion packs for Doom 3. I know the original incarnations and many of the source ports of DOOM and DOOM 2 supported multiplayer, but I don't seem to be able to find the option to start or join a multiplayer game in the version of The Ultimate DOOM that is bundled with the DOOM 3 BFG edition.

How do I play multiplayer The Ultimate DOOM - BFG edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native option to play multiplayer DOOM with the version bundled with DOOM 3 - BFG Edition. When you start the game you're presented with the game selection screen;

[image]

When you select either DOOM or DOOM 2, you're presented with a limited version of the traditional start menu;

[image]

Selecting 'New Game' or any of the other options does not provide you with a multiplayer option.

As a workaround, however, [it is possible to use the data files for both DOOM and DOOM 2 with one of the game engine ports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96840/27134) and many of these (for example DOOMSDAY/jDOOM) *do* provide multiplayer support, allowing you to play multiplayer games of DOOM.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplayer for Doom and Doom 2 are available for PS3 and Xbox, but not for PC.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try Classic RBDoom 3 BFG mod which recently got multiplayer support for Ultimate DOOM and DOOM II.

Available Links:

https://github.com/MadDeCoDeR/Classic-RBDOOM-3-BFG/releases/latest

http://www.moddb.com/mods/classic-rbdoom-3-bfg-edition/downloads