# Is it possible to use one of the ports?

Tags: doom, doom-3-bfg-edition, doom-2

DOOM, like many other ID games, has had its source code released to the public, and a community has built itself up around creating new content for these older games.

Such examples of ports and remakes using this source code include DOOMSDAY, jDOOM, and others.

The copies of DOOM and DOOM 2 released with DOOM 3 BFG Edition doesn't include any kind of graphical updates, the ability to run in a window, etc.

Is it possible to use the use the game data from DOOM 3 BFG Edition to play DOOM and DOOM 2 using one of the alternative game engines to gain this functionality? If so, what files do I need to copy from the DOOM 3 BFG Edition folder to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the game data for DOOM and DOOM 2 with one of the ports.

In my instance I used jDOOM and I simply copied the .WAD files from within the installation folder to the jDOOM data folder, which were then picked up by jDOOM. One issue I have noticed is that this hasn't picked up the fourth episode of The Ultimate DOOM but I imagine this is an issue with the port rather than the WADs.

**Where's all the data?**

The WAD files can be located in `<DOOM 3 BFG Edition installation folder>\base\wads`

Inside this folder you will find the following files;

```
DOOM.WAD         The Ultimate DOOM game data
DOOM2.WAD        DOOM 2 game data
NERVE.WAD        DOOM 2 expansion: No Rest for the Living
```